# Leaflet -Disable Opacity Slider

Tags: leaflet

I'm using the Leaflet HTML output generated by MapTiler with some additional customizations. Very basic stuff. I think I've got most of what I want to do sorted out. However, there's an opacity slider on the screen that's interfering with my layer selector icon widget control thing.

I don't need the opacity slider. It's just a base map (from an image) and the layers won't have anything but markers and polygons on them. There's no need for there to be an opacity slider that will hide the base map.

Problem is, I can't get rid of it. There are loads of questions on SO about how to make it apply to this layer or that layer or layer groups, but nothing about removing it. I can't find anything in the Leaflet docs about how to turn it off, but the examples don't show it by default and there doesn't appear to be anything in their sample code showing it explicitly being disabled.

What am I missing and how can I get rid of this thing?

I feel like it should be a tileLayer thing, but I can't find an option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was solved by removing the #slider CSS. I don't know if it put it somewhere else that I can't see or if it removed it completely. But it's gone, which is all I care about.

Edit: Also the "slider" input. Can't believe I overlooked that.